# Can I upgrade to an SSD with the newest macOS from an old HDD with old macOS on MacBook Pro 2012?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade

As per the title, my MBP 2012's hdd with Mavericks installed had recently failed and I am looking to replace it with an SSD.

I also have a MacBook Pro 2017 that I'm going to use to install macOS Catalina on the new SSD, so that I can directly use my MBP 2012 without having to wait for internet recovery.

Question is, can the MBP 2012 recognize the Catalina-installed SSD, even if I assume the firmware is for the old Mavericks? Or do I have to go through internet recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking, any volume with MacOS on it should boot on any Mac that the OS supports.

There are some exceptions to that rule, of course. The newer T2-chip Macs complicate things with their SecureBoot settings. And some Macs require firmware updates on their internal drive before they can use APFS volumes -- though in your case the EFI partition will be created when you install the OS.

So it should work.

The better alternative would be to create an 'installer disk' on a small USB thumb drive, and boot to that, on the 2012 MBP, to install on the SSD once fitted internally.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you so much for the response!